# SQL - Length of FirstName and LastName

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am able to find the length of a person's FirstName and LastName by doing this:

```
SELECT LEN(FirstName + ' ' + LastName) AS NameLength
FROM dbo.Employees
```

That gives me the length of both the FirstName and LastName as well as the space in between.

What I am trying to accomplish is have the words, "Your full name is (NameLength) characters" I tried to add the two together but I get `converting error`.

Comment: Removed the mysql tag because the syntax suggests SQL Server.

Comment: Note that your code is wrong (and gleefully copied by some responses below), the length of a field in an SQL DBMS is *not* the length of the string it stores. And what you're poking and prodding are fields, not strings.

Comment: I doubt they want the length of the column declaration given the example.

Comment: Mhm, and what will his code (and yours) return for `FirstName` and `LastName` declared as `char(50)`, regardless of what's stored inside?

Comment: @Blindy Who would declare a name field as a char(anything)?

Comment: @Blindy, `LEN()` returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx  Try it out: `declare @YouBeWrong char(50);SET @YouBeWrong='Blindy';select LEN(@YouBeWrong);` you will get 6 and not 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the number to varchar in order to append it to text, like

```
select 'your name is ' + cast(LEN(FirstName + ' ' + LastName) as varchar(64)) + ' chars '
```

(you have this tagged as both mysql and sql-server, so i'll just put a sql-server example here)

Comment: So when you use the cast function, does it convert it? Also, how come you added the varchar(64) part. Sorry I'm trying to understand it

Comment: LEN(NULL) will return a NULL.  When concatenating a string with NULL, you will get NULL.  As a result, I would recommend that you wrap the `cast()` in an `INSULL()` or in some way handle a missing name(s) that will cause the entire string to become NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the result of the `LEN` to a `varchar`:

```
Select  'Your full name is ' + cast(Len(FirstName + ' ' + LastName) as varchar(2)) + ' characters'
```

Edit:

Also, to appease @Blindy:

```
Select  'Your full name is ' + cast(Len(rtrim(FirstName) + ' ' + LastName) as varchar(2)) + ' characters'
```

Comment: @Blindy is wrong, `LEN()` returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks. so no RTRIM is necessary. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx Try it out: `declare @YouBeWrong char(50);SET @YouBeWrong='Blindy';select LEN(@YouBeWrong);` you'll get a 5 and not 50.

Comment: @KM Not exactly.  In this specific case, the `RTRIM` is needed: `Declare @YouBeRight char(50) = '0123456789';Select LEN(@YouBeRight + ' ' + @YouBeRight)` returns 61.